# How to add a wifi network to the list of known ones in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am working on an app that needs to add a wifi network (i.e., SSID and password) to the list of known ones of the mobile phone, so that it connects to that network automatically even when seeing it for the first time.

I already did this on Android, and now I will start working on the iPhone version.

**Question**: On the iPhone, is it possible to have my app (when it runs for the first time) add a wifi network to the list of known ones of the device, and if so, any hints regarding how to do it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'll readily admit to not having actually done any research into this, but at first glance, it sounds like the sort of thing Apple would prohibit – I can imagine it being a pretty glaring security hole.  Maybe someone'll prove me wrong, though.

Comment: @Riley, yeah I feared this as well, that is why I decided to ask first for more experienced iOS developers. Let's see what others say, and thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible on iOS.

Apple doesn't provide any public APIs to add network SSIDs or passwords.

The most you can do is to enable your app to manage the user's authentication for a public network, (as is done for things like Boingo and The Cloud). In this case, when the user joins a network, instead of a webpage opening to authenticate, your app can launch and provide the authentication - but that is as far as you can go.

We asked for clarification on this point to Apple in the dev forums and were told that it is definitely not possible. (I will try to dig out the link to that post for you when I get more time. Else, search your query on the dev forums and it might show up).

Answer (score 0):

so it would seem that with iOS 6, there may be a way to do this. Boingo appear to allow a user to turn on "Auto Login" and it will login/authenticate against the access point without the user interacting/authenticating manually (I haven't tried it myself though). Is there new API calls in iOS 6 that now allows this? [See this article](http://www.boingo.com/pr/articles/?a=2013-01-29-boingo-releases-enhanced-wi-finder-app-for-ios-6&id=761&date=2013-01-29).